# Stop infinite function in kotlin using coroutines - difference between async and GlobalScope.async

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to wrap some Java-callback function using timeout. Callback may be never called, so it should be interrupted with exception. Here was my first try:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    withTimeout(500) {
        async {
            notCalledCallback()
        }.await()
    }
    Unit
}

private suspend fun notCalledCallback() = suspendCoroutine<Boolean> { cont ->
    startScanning(object : SomeCallback {
        override fun done() {
            cont.resume(true)
        }
    })
}

fun startScanning(callBack: SomeCallback) {
    // callback may never be invoked
    //    callBack.done()
}

interface SomeCallback {
    fun done()
}
```

I expected to have a `TimeoutCancellationException` after 500ms, but actually it never happens. However if I replace

```
async {
 notCalledCallback()
}.await()
```

with

```
GlobalScope.async {
 notCalledCallback()
}.await()
```

it starts to work. Why? What is the difference between `async` and `GlobalScope.async` in this case and why it works in latter case?

Comment: My guess is that in the first case the timer runs on the same thread that is blocked by infinityFunction(). In the second case it probably runs on Dispatchers.Default, which is a thread pool managed by kotlinx.coroutines library.

Comment: Hi, not sure about it. If I replace async with withContext(Dispatchers.Default) it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try replacing `Thread.sleep` (which blocks the thread) with  `delay` (which yields to other coroutines). In your real "infinity function", you might want to periodically call `yield` to share the thread with other coroutines, and give `withTimeout` a chance to cancel it.

Comment: Actually this function start scanning for bluetooth devices and report results in callback. If desired device won't be found within specific time, it should raise an exception. Unfortunately I see no place for yield in this function (callback may be never called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually very simple: `suspendCoroutine()` is not cancellable. You need to instead use a very similar function: [suspendCancellableCoroutine()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html).

Please be aware that ideally you should not only swap one function with another, but also properly cancel the asynchronous operation before resuming the coroutine. Otherwise you leak this background operation as it is entirely detached from your execution context. You can detect cancellations with `cont.invokeOnCancellation()`, as described in the documentation linked above.

If you use `GlobalScope` then you `await()` for the operation in your current execution context, but the operation itself runs in another context. In this case if you cancel, then you cancel waiting, but you don't cancel the operation and you don't care whether it completes or not.

Comment: URL can be amended -> You need to instead use a very similar function: [suspendCancellableCoroutine()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1)
    }
```

This block of code does not comply with coroutine practices and doesn't offer the coroutine framework any opportunity to cancel it.

A correct implementation of `infinityFunction()` would be to simply call [`awaitCancellation`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-cancellation.html).  Alternately, you could replace `Thread.sleep` with `delay`.

Notably, using `GlobalScope` actually breaks the correct relationship between your coroutines (making the `async` block not a child of the calling coroutine), with the result that your `main` function doesn't wait for `infinityFunction()` to *properly* finish cancelling.  While this appears to make your code work, it actually just conceals a worse bug.

Comment: Thanks for respone. Actually I know sleep is disastrous idea when it comes to work with coroutines, but just wanted to make whole problem easier to understand. In real code I have a callback, which may never be called. I edited my question.

Comment: I did discuss what happens with `GlobalScope`.  Additionally, the coroutines library does provide a correct way to address the callback use case: use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` instead of `suspendCoroutine`.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now! Unfortunately I cannot accept both answers.